# The meaning of a symbol in the proposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, self-learning

[image]

The question is what's the meaning of the symbol $\phi$?

If it just a mapping,what's the mean of the equation?

I guess it's $\phi(x)$, $x$ is the element of $M$.
Then $\phi(x)$ is the element of $M$ too,the equation will mean a element of $M$ plus a element of ideal a equal to zero.

We haven't define the sum.The binary operation of module should be $A \times M \to M$.
The symbol $\phi$ is not $\phi(x)$.

Could you tell me what's meaning of a symbol in the proposition or what's the mean of the equation.

I'm sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: Anyhow, an $A$-module endomorphism is a homomorphism $\phi:A\to A$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar  Sorry for my poor English.Yes,It's a homomorphism,but what's it mean in the equation?That's my question.If it's just a mapping,it doesn't make any sense.So I guess it's f(x),but it still  doesn't make sense.

Comment: The set $\operatorname{End}_A(M)$ of $A$-linear endomorphisms of $M$ is naturally a (noncommutative) $A$-algebra, so the equation does indeed make sense.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld What's the meaning of m+x=0?(m∈M,x∈a⊆A)

Comment: I am not claiming that means anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of endomorphisms of an $A$-module $M$, just like the set of linear mappings from a vector space to itself, form a ring, if you define the operations pointwise. In other words, if $\phi,\psi$ are a $A$-module endomorphism, define $$\begin{eqnarray}
  (\phi \mathbf{+} \psi) &\,:\,& M \to M &\,:\,& x \mapsto \phi(x) + \psi(x) \\
  (\phi \circ \psi) &\,:\,& M \to M &\,:\,& x \mapsto \phi(\psi(x)) \\
  \mathbf{1} &\,:\,& M \to M &\,:\,& x \mapsto x \\
  \mathbf{0} &\,:\,& M \to M &\,:\,& x \mapsto 0 \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
With that $\phi^n$ simply means $\underbrace{\phi\cdot\ldots\cdot\phi}_{\textrm{$n$ times}}$, i.e. $\phi^n(x) = \phi(\ldots\phi(x)\ldots)$. Just like as for numbers, we set $$
  \phi^0 := \mathbf{1} \text{,}
$$
i.e. for every endomorphism $\phi$, we define $\phi^0$ to be the identical mapping $x \mapsto x$.

Additionally, since you can multiply elements of an $A$-module with elements of $A$ (just like you can multiply and vector in a vector space with a scalar), every element $c \in A$ naturally corresponds to the $A$-module endomorphism $$
  \mathbf{c} \,:\, M \to M \,:\, x \mapsto c\cdot x \text{.}
$$

This allows you to evaluate poylnomials $p \in A[t]$ for arbitrary endomorphisms $\phi$. Let $$
  p(t) = a_n t^n + \ldots + a_1 t + a_0 \in A[t] \text{.}
$$
Then, evaluating $p$ at $\phi$, yields $$
  p(\phi) = \mathbf{a_n} \circ \phi^n \mathbf{+} \ldots \mathbf{+} \mathbf{a_1}\circ \phi \mathbf{+} \mathbf{a_0} \text{,}
$$
where $\mathbf{a_i}$ stands for the *endomorphism* corresponding to $a_i$, i.e. for the map $x \mapsto a_i\cdot x$. The expression $p(\phi)$ is thus endomorphism defined as the sum of producs of endomorphisms. Let's now apply an $x$ to that endomorphism, i.e. compute $$\begin{eqnarray}
  p(\phi)(x) &=& \left(\mathbf{a_n} \circ\phi^n \mathbf{+} \ldots \mathbf{+} \mathbf{a_1}\circ \phi \mathbf{+} \mathbf{a_0}\right)(x) \\
  &=&  \mathbf{a_n} \circ\phi^n(x) + \ldots + \mathbf{a_1}\circ \phi(x) + \mathbf{a_0}(x) \\
  &=&  a_n \cdot\phi^n(x) + \ldots + a_1 \cdot\phi(x) + a_0\cdot x \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
Note that bold symbols (e.g. $\mathbf{a_i}$ and $\mathbf{+}$) and $\circ$ represent operations on *endomorphisms*, while their regular counterparts represent the operations on the $A$-module $M$. It follows that $p(\phi)$ is simply the endomorphism $$
  p(\phi) \,:\, M \to M \,:\, x \mapsto a_n\cdot \phi^n(x) + \ldots + a_1\cdot \phi(x) + a_0\cdot x \text{.}
$$

Comment: there's a typo in that last equation, but otherwise, good answer.

Comment: Thanks. anxn+…a1x is the element of M, a0 is the element of A.We have defined a*m that a∈A,m∈M,but we haven't defined a+m.So what's the meaning of p(x)=anxn+…a1x+a0?

Comment: @amateur Look at the last paragraph... it tells how *exactly* how to evaluate a $p(\phi)$. You don't add $a_0$ at the end, you add $a_0\cdot x$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Where? I don't see it... One $x$ was bold though, maybe you meant that?

Comment: "$a_n\cdot \phi^n(x) + a_1\cdot \phi(x) + a_0\cdot x\text{.}$"

Comment: I still confused about the equation of the proposition on the book.What's the meaning of f^n+....+an=0?It's like 2f+5g+3=0,f&g are functions. 2f(x)+5g(x)+3=0 makes sense,f+g+3=0 doesn't make sense.

Comment: @amateur OK, I tried to explain in a bit more detail.